# While loop duplicates lines to new sheet until cell = 0

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to copy a row over to a new sheet multiple times (based on user response).

After the row has been copied over `x` number of times, it should move to another sheet and then be removed from the original sheet.

I have it almost working but the `while()` loop will only subtract from the active cell once in row `z` and then just keeps repeating.

I would appreciate any help. Here is what I have:

```
function dupLines()
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var POStatus = ss.getSheetByName("PO STATUS");
    var awarded = ss.getSheetByName("AWARDED");
    var cell = s.getCurrentCell();
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();

    function getTimeStamp()
    {
        var now = new Date();
        return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() );
    }

    while (cellValue > '0')
    {
        POStatus.insertRows(19,1);
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetPO = POStatus.getRange("A19");
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(targetPO); 
        POStatus.getRange("X19").setValue(getTimeStamp()); 
        cell.setValue(cellValue - 1);
    }

    awarded.insertRows(19,1);
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetAwd = awarded.getRange("A19");

    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(targetAwd); 
    awarded.getRange("X19").setValue(getTimeStamp());
    s.deleteRow(row);
}
```

******************* UPDATE ********************

This is what I have that is now working. I am sure it can be simplified?

```
function onOpen(e){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('QUEUE MENU')
  .addItem('Create POs', 'CreatePOs')
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem('Sidebar Queue', 'openSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}


function CreatePOs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var POStatus = ss.getSheetByName("PO STATUS");
  var awarded = ss.getSheetByName("AWARDED");


  if(s.getName() == "QUEUE" && r.getColumn() == 22 && r.getValue() == true) {

    userInput(); 
    dupLines();
    moveToAwarded();
} 
else 
{ 
     Browser.msgBox('Please check box in PO Status column.');

};
}

function userInput() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 4).activate();
  var prompt = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('How many lines do you want to send to PO STATUS?', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(prompt.getSelectedButton() === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK){
    value = prompt.getResponseText();
  }
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(value);
}



function dupLines(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var POStatus = ss.getSheetByName("PO STATUS");
  var awarded = ss.getSheetByName("AWARDED");
  var cell = s.getCurrentCell();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();

  function getTimeStamp() {
  var now = new Date();
    return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
            (now.getDate()) + '/' +
             now.getFullYear() );
}


  while (cellValue > 0) {

     POStatus.insertRows(19,1);
     var row = r.getRow();
     var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
     var targetPO = POStatus.getRange("A19");
     s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(targetPO);
     POStatus.getRange("X19").setValue(getTimeStamp());
     cellValue--;

  } }


  function moveToAwarded() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var POStatus = ss.getSheetByName("PO STATUS");
    var awarded = ss.getSheetByName("AWARDED");

    function getTimeStamp() {
      var now = new Date();
      return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
              (now.getDate()) + '/' +
               now.getFullYear() );
}


    awarded.insertRows(19,1);

     var row = r.getRow();
     var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
     var targetAwd = awarded.getRange("A19");
     s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(targetAwd);
     awarded.getRange("X19").setValue(getTimeStamp());
     s.deleteRow(row);
  }



function openSidebar(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar').setTitle('Queue Quick View');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Comment: function dupLines(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var POStatus = ss.getSheetByName("PO STATUS");
    var awarded = ss.getSheetByName("AWARDED");
    var cell = s.getCurrentCell();
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();

  
function getTimeStamp() {
    var now = new Date();
    return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
           (now.getDate()) + '/' +
            now.getFullYear() );
}

Comment: while (cellValue > '0') {

     POStatus.insertRows(19,1);
     var row = r.getRow();
     var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
     var targetPO = POStatus.getRange("A19");
     s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(targetPO);
     POStatus.getRange("X19").setValue(getTimeStamp());
     cell.setValue(cellValue - 1);
    
    
}

Comment: awarded.insertRows(19,1);
     var row = r.getRow();
     var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
     var targetAwd = awarded.getRange("A19");
     s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(targetAwd);
     awarded.getRange("X19").setValue(getTimeStamp());
    s.deleteRow(row);
 

}

Comment: Move all your code back into the question.  Select it all and press control K.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems (and there may be others) that I can spot is in:

```
    cell.setValue(cellValue - 1); // Changes the value in the cell but not in the script
```

This changes the value in the active cell. But it does not change the value of the variable `cellValue`.

Try this while-loop instead:

```
while (cellValue > '0')
    {
        POStatus.insertRows(19,1);
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetPO = POStatus.getRange("A19");
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(targetPO); 
        POStatus.getRange("X19").setValue(getTimeStamp());
        cellValue--; // Reduce value by 1
        cell.setValue(cellValue); // Set new value in cell
    }
```

---

A few other suggestions that may help:

**1**
`while (cellValue > '0')` is checking for a string value `'0'`. It works because alphabetically, all positive numbers are greater than 1. But strictly speaking you want `while (cellValue > 0)`

**2**
`cell.setValue(cellValue);` has cosmetic value, i.e. it updates the cell. But the updated value is not used in the script.

[Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) suggest not making unnecessary calls to the sheet. So you could do without that line and have the script run a bit faster.